# Problem with git: remote 'refs/heads/master' is not an ancestor of local 'refs/heads/master'

Tags: git

I faced to a situation which I don't understand. I have a remote git repo running on WebDAV / apache. Just to be sure, I logged on the server and run "chown -R wwwrun:www *" and "git update-server-info" on the relevant directory (as root, obviously).

Now, I do:

```
git clone http://myserver/myrepo
```

then:

```
$git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: http://myserver/myrepo
  Push  URL: http://myserver/myrepo
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    master   tracked
    trunk    tracked
    trunk2.0 tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (fast-forwardable)
```

and then I change any file, stage, commit and try to push, which results in:

```
error: remote 'refs/heads/master' is not an ancestor of
local 'refs/heads/master'.
```

Obviously, any attempt to pull is pointless:

```
$git pull
Already up-to-date.
```

The repository was just fine a few days ago. How can I work with it again?

Comment: Have you recently rebased or changed the branch from what is on your origin? Git will not let you push if you've removed already published commits unless you force it. See http://book.git-scm.com/3_distributed_workflows.html

Comment: Someone had tried to push but this resulted in "curl HTTP error 403" - this is how the problem has started. I would expect that something in the remote repository setup is broken (e.g. a file locked, wrong HEAD, etc.) I plan to make a remote clone of the most recent of the local repositories to the server, hopefully this won't mess up too much. But maybe there is a better solution

Comment: This is possibly the same problem as http://serverfault.com/questions/256376/cant-push-to-git-remote-repositories/460288#460288 (same error message)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I resolved the problem as I wrote in a comment. I used one of the local repositories to make a bare remote repo and everyone else got synchronized with it.